# Where do paths for images go in Backbone?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

The paths are used to populate the user image or profile picture.

Is this considered model data?

Or is this considered view data?

Comment: By "user image" - do you mean a profile picture for a user? Is this image associated with your user model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds to me like you are talking about an attribute of your user model. If this is the case, your image paths should sit within the same code that handles all the user model behavior.

To answer directly:

Your image paths are model data.

Comment: to make things more complicated, what if the image paths are derived from the model data? i.e. - `path = model_token + constant`

Comment: It's still data that is directly related to the model.

Comment: I always thought of model data as a row in the database.  The path is not in the database as it would be redundant to repeat it for each row.

Comment: Backbone lets you decide for yourself where you want to put it. If you are more comfortable putting it in the View, go ahead. I would personally put it in the model, since it's behind the scenes data.

Comment: I know you here the analogy that database rows are similar to model data but to make life easy and not have to think so much about little things, I 'm just going to make this standard.  A row of data in the DB table is a model.  A one to one relationship.